Microsoft Entra Id - Enable Email OTP for all guest users
I am trying to figure out why two users create with the graph API has different login experiences.
The users are created as guests. One has the email xxx@mac.com and the other has xxx@yahoo.com
The yahoo user gets a login screen with a send code button and the @mac user get a screen with a prompt for password.
I have compared the users, and they are, as expected the same. When it comes to the properties they have.
I want all external users to be authenticated with an OTP send by mail.
There are so many properties to set in Azure so please write in the comment section if you want more information.
UPDATE
I created a new Gmail and Proton mail account and they also work.
